# Нужно оптимизировать готовый код! Хелп

Tags: python-3.x

```
def scramble(s1, s2):
    num = 0
    s = s1
    for x in s2:
        if (s.count(x) >= 1):
            s = s.replace(x,"",1)
            num+=1
    result = True if num == len(s2) else False
    return result
scramble('javscripts', 'javascript')
```

Суть программы: Возращает true, если символы из первой строки можно расставить таким образом, чтобы получилось 2 строка, иначе false. Пример: В первой строке не хватает одной буквы "а", чтобы получилась строка 2, следовательно, возращает false. Код рабочий, но нужно оптимизировать. Новичок в этом деле)

Comment: можете привести несколько примеров строк? Что например должна вернуть `scramble("abb", "abba")`?

Comment: false, т.к не хватает еще одной буквы. Написал же в примере)

Answer (score 0):

```
    for c in set(s2):
        if s1.count(c) < s2.count(c):
            return False
    return True
```

Вот ответ на мой вопрос. Без использования модулей и пр.

Comment: Это неоптимизированный вариант.

Comment: Скорость выполнения значительно быстрее моего и мне этого хватило

Answer (score 0):

1. Проверяем длину строк. Если длина первой строки меньше второй
2. Каждую строку преобразовываем строку в список символов и сортируем их
3. Пробегаем по второму списку и ищем символ в первом

```
def scramble(s1, s2):
  s1Len = len(s1)
  if s1Len < len(s2):
      return False
  c1 = list(s1)
  c1.sort()
  c2 = list(s2)
  c2.sort()
  idx = 0
  for x in c2:
    while (idx < s1Len and c1[idx] < x):
      idx += 1
    if (idx == s1Len or c1[idx] > x):
      return False
    idx += 1;
  return True
```

https://repl.it/repls/SmugLimpingContent